# How to display multiple images in a html div, using javascript's array and loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, profile

I want to display multiple images in an HTML `<div>`, so that user can select select the 'avatar' for their profile. I have written this javascript, but it displays only last image in array.

```
const array1 =[
"Multiavatar1.png",
"Multiavatar2.png", "Multiavatar3.png", "Multiavatar4.png", "Multiavatar5.png", "Multiavatar6.png", "Multiavatar7.png", "Multiavatar8.png", "Multiavatar9.png", "Multiavatar10.png", "Multiavatar11.png", "Multiavatar12.png", "Multiavatar13.png", "Multiavatar14.png", "Multiavatar15.png", "Multiavatar16.png", "Multiavatar17.png", "Multiavatar18.png", "Multiavatar19.png", "Multiavatar20.png", "Multiavatar21.png", "Multiavatar22.png", "Multiavatar23.png", "Multiavatar24.png", "Multiavatar25.png", "Multiavatar26.png", "Multiavatar27.png", "Multiavatar28.png", "Multiavatar29.png", "Multiavatar30.png", "Multiavatar31.png", "Multiavatar32.png", "Multiavatar33.png", "Multiavatar34.png", "Multiavatar35.png", "Multiavatar36.png", "Multiavatar37.png", "Multiavatar38.png", "Multiavatar39.png", "Multiavatar40.png", "Multiavatar41.png", "Multiavatar42.png",
                    ];

array1.forEach( element => {
            var image = `<img src="avatar/${element}" alt="img">`;
            document.getElementById('avatar_div').innerHTML = image;
});
```

But apparently I tried using the below script in a separate file, and this worked.

```
const array1 =[                             "Multiavatar1.png",
"Multiavatar2.png",
"Multiavatar3.png",
"Multiavatar4.png", "Multiavatar5.png", "Multiavatar6.png", "Multiavatar7.png", "Multiavatar8.png", "Multiavatar9.png", "Multiavatar10.png", "Multiavatar11.png", "Multiavatar12.png", "Multiavatar13.png", "Multiavatar14.png", "Multiavatar15.png", "Multiavatar16.png", "Multiavatar17.png", "Multiavatar18.png", "Multiavatar19.png", "Multiavatar20.png", "Multiavatar21.png", "Multiavatar22.png", "Multiavatar23.png", "Multiavatar24.png", "Multiavatar25.png", "Multiavatar26.png", "Multiavatar27.png", "Multiavatar28.png", "Multiavatar29.png", "Multiavatar30.png", "Multiavatar31.png", "Multiavatar32.png", "Multiavatar33.png", "Multiavatar34.png", "Multiavatar35.png", "Multiavatar36.png", "Multiavatar37.png", "Multiavatar38.png", "Multiavatar39.png", "Multiavatar40.png", "Multiavatar41.png", "Multiavatar42.png",
                    ];

array1.forEach( element => {
                
                var h = `<img src="avatar/${element}" alt="img"><br>`;
            
        document.write(h);
});
```

Can anyone explain me, what am
I doing wrong in first script.

And suggestions for my code to work?

Answer (score 1):

Your first sample is not working because you are overwriting the previous HTML.

Your second sample is working because `document.write` appends the HTML.

To make the first sample work, use `+=` ([addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment)) instead of `=`:

```js
const array1 = [
    "Multiavatar1.png",
    "Multiavatar2.png", "Multiavatar3.png", "Multiavatar4.png", "Multiavatar5.png", "Multiavatar6.png", "Multiavatar7.png", "Multiavatar8.png", "Multiavatar9.png", "Multiavatar10.png", "Multiavatar11.png", "Multiavatar12.png", "Multiavatar13.png", "Multiavatar14.png", "Multiavatar15.png", "Multiavatar16.png", "Multiavatar17.png", "Multiavatar18.png", "Multiavatar19.png", "Multiavatar20.png", "Multiavatar21.png", "Multiavatar22.png", "Multiavatar23.png", "Multiavatar24.png", "Multiavatar25.png", "Multiavatar26.png", "Multiavatar27.png", "Multiavatar28.png", "Multiavatar29.png", "Multiavatar30.png", "Multiavatar31.png", "Multiavatar32.png", "Multiavatar33.png", "Multiavatar34.png", "Multiavatar35.png", "Multiavatar36.png", "Multiavatar37.png", "Multiavatar38.png", "Multiavatar39.png", "Multiavatar40.png", "Multiavatar41.png", "Multiavatar42.png",
];

array1.forEach(element => {
    var image = `<img src="avatar/${element}" alt="img">`;
    document.getElementById('avatar_div').innerHTML += image;
});
```

Demo:

```js
const array1 = [
  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"
];

array1.forEach(element => {
  var image = ` <img src = "${element}" alt = "img">`;
  document.getElementById('avatar_div').innerHTML += image;
});
``
```

```html
<div id="avatar_div"></div>
```